# Assigning Unique Codes to Strings, Many Less Codes Than Rows

Tags: r, economics

I am working with a dataset where I must assign unique codes to a few dozen string descriptors. I don't know how to do this because every time I use the unique() command, R returns an error stating that it cannot produce unique codes because there would be significantly less codes than rows. For example, see below.

I have a few dozen string descriptors, meaning I need a few dozen unique codes that would correspond to those string descriptors. However, when I use the unique() command to produce those unique codes, R returns an error because those few dozen unique codes would then be applied to a dataset consisting of millions of observations. How do I assign those unique codes to those millions of observations?

I have tried the unique() command. This has failed.

Comment: Try: `myData$newID <- as.integer(as.factor(myData$myColumn))`

Comment: Need more of the code being used.